# Android Random Number llegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to generate Random Number from 0 to 43 range. But at Some Devices (OnePlus Android 5.0.2 and Nexus 5.1) it is throwing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0. I am not able to catch that exception Below is my Code to generate the random Number.

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int maximum = mListofStrings.getMyString().size() - 1;
    Log.e("Max",""+maximum);
    Mint.logEvent("Maximum", MintLogLevel.Error);
    int randomNum;
    try{

       // randomNum = rand.nextInt(43);
        randomNum = rand.nextInt(maximum);
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        randomNum = 8;
    }

    Log.e("random number", randomNum+"");
```

And also Log is

```
1   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
2   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
3   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
4   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
5   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
6   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
7   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
8   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
9   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
11  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
12Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
13  at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
14  at com.algo.toiletbreak.ShareActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
15  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
16  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
17  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
18  ... 10 more
```

Comment: Is it possible that `mListofStrings.getMyString()` is empty, such that `size() == 0` and `maximum == -1`??  That would explain the exception you're seeing.

Comment: @blazetopher my List is hard coded with 43 items. Even i have tried with rand.nextint(43) but the issue is same.

Comment: I've assumed that the exception came from the call to `nextInt`.  On what line did the exception get thrown?

Comment: Wow, that you get the same exception with a hard-coded input is very bizarre...

Comment: @regttmen Random.class line 182

Comment: @malik Umar are you able to solve the error can u share it ?

Answer (score 3):

If the `nextInt` method is complaining that its argument was `0`, then `maximum` was `0`.  That implies that `mListofStrings.getMyString().size()` returned `1`.  There's no point in attempting to generating a random number from `0` inclusive through `0` exclusive; such an `int` doesn't exist.  But the parameter value is one more than the maximum random value that can be returned.  This means that you should not subtract `1` when assigning `maximum`.

```
int maximum = mListofStrings.getMyString().size();
```

You may also want to test if the `size()` method returns `0`, and handle that case specially.

Comment: my List is hard coded with 43 items. Even i have tried with rand.nextint(43) but the issue is same.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int randInt(int min, int max) 
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

Pass min as 0 and max as 43 (as you said) and get the random number in the range.